# If a finite nonempty set of real numbers has a maximum then it has a minimum, prove.

Tags: order-theory, real-numbers

so as the title says. I first proved that all finite nonempty sets of real numbers have maximum, but I cannot see how from this I can prove that it also has a minimum.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It's quite easy to prove by induction that every finite non-empty set of real numbers (more generally of any total order) has both a maximum and a minimum. This formulation of the problem is very weird.

Comment: @GitGud yeah i know but this is the formulation so yeah ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express your set as $A = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$. Denote $\{-x_1, \ldots, -x_n\}$ by $-A$. By condition, there exists $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ such that $-x_i = \max(-A)$. Try to show that $x_i = \min A$.

---

Details: $-x_i = \max(-A)$ means  that $-x_i \geq -x_k$ for all $k \in \{1,2, \ldots, n\}$, which in turn is equivalent to say that $x_i  \leq x_k$ for all $k \in \{1,2, \ldots, n\}$, which exactly means $x_i = \min A$.

Comment: That is the main problem, it seems intuitive but i cnanot seem to find a way to show that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $A$ is your set, what can you say about the maximum of 
$$B= \{ -x |x \in A \} ?$$

Comment: So maX of a is minimum of b. Could you help me write it formally?